# Simulate the Linux command tee in C

Tags: c, linux, pipe, tee

I have to do the simulation of the command `tee` in C for Linux. How does `tee` work internally? It looks like a T-shaped pipe, so should I use a pipe? Is there a special kind of pipe?

Comment: 'man tee' will tell you all about the command. Tee allows you to split the stdout of a one program into a file and to stdout.

Comment: @wich Please stop adding the homework tag to questions. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tee takes stdin and copies the data stream to stdout as well as a file given as an option, it can be used in many very different situations.

An implementation in C is quite simple, just make a program that copies all data from stdin to stdout, but also use the same output statements for stdout on a file that you opened based on the command line argument.

basically in pseudo code:

```
file f = open(argv[1])
while (! end of file stdin) {
  buffer = read stdin
  write stdout buffer
  write f buffer
}
close(f)
```

Note that you don't really have to do anything with pipes, your shell will sort out the pipes, the program only has to copy data from one stream to two others.

Comment: Ok, I have this:
    #include <stdio.h>

    main(int agrc, char **argv[]){
 
 FILE *fp;
 FILE *fp1;
 
 fp = fopen(*argv[1], "r");
 fp1 = fopen(*argv[2], "w");
 
 char buffer[100];
 
 while (feof(fp) == 0){  
   fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer);
   printf("%s", buffer);
   fprintf(fp1, buffer);
 } 
 fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp1); 
   }

I execute
    ./a.out hello.txt hello2.txt

But... segmentation fault. What is wrong here? By the way, it compiles correctly.
Thank you.

Comment: It can be one of several reasons. One, you allocate a buffer with limited size, if any line is longer than that size you will access memory outside the buffer space. My suggestion is to not use fscanf and printf but use functions that just read and write a sequence of bytes instead. Two is that you do not do any error checking, if the fopen fails it will return NULL, the other functions will try to access that NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I finished the program!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[]){

FILE *fp, *fp1;
char buffer;

if(argc != 4){
    printf("\nError");
    printf("\nSintaxis: tee [archivo1] [archivo2]\n");
    exit(0);
}

if(strcmp(argv[1], "tee") == 0){
    fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    fp1 = fopen(argv[3], "w");

    printf("\Content in %s:\n", argv[2]);

    while(!feof(fp)){
        buffer = fgetc(fp);
        fputc(buffer, fp1);
        printf("%c", buffer);
    }

    printf("\n\n%s received %s\n", argv[3], argv[2]);   

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    }
    else
        printf("\nThe first argument have to be tee\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I wrote about 20 years ago to implement TEE in Windows.  I have been using this with various batch files since then.  Note the flush command at the end of each line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <share.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2 )
    {
        printf ("Error:  No output file name given, example:  theCmd 2>&1 |ltee outputFileName \n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *Out = _fsopen(argv[argc-1], "a", _SH_DENYWR);
    if (NULL == Out)
    {
        char buf[300];
        sprintf_s(buf, 300, "Error openning %s", argv[argc-1]);
        perror(buf);
        return 1;
    }
    int ch;
    while ( EOF != (ch=getchar()))
    {
        putchar(ch);
        putc(ch, Out);
        if ( '\n' == ch )
            fflush(Out);
    }
    _flushall();
    fclose(Out);
    return 0;
}
```